# How to send array Object from NodeJS to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to send my database output, which is an array to javascript file to display it in select options. I tried,

```
response.render('/entry.js',{output : outputArray});
```

In entry JS file,

```
var outputArray = "<%= output %>";
```

But it is printing as it is.
Kindly help me on this

Comment: share your piece of code

Comment: In your view, iterate over your array and bind each item to <option/>

Comment: I am unable to get the object in javascript file. Is there any way to get it

Comment: Try in your script in the html. `var arrayOutput = <%- JSON.stringify(output) %>;` and declare this **before** your js file, now in your js file call `console.log(arrayOutput)`. It seems to me your trying to reference the ejs variable in a file its not accessible in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is a Ajax Call to NodeJS server which query the database and returns JSON output into your page.

Comment: I am unable to get the object in javascript file. Is there any way to get it. We are not using AJAX.

Comment: You could do XHTML request (which is AJAX without Jquery). You could send it also through Websocket into a browser.

How it the project structure, Does the back end run through NodeJS using some sort of lib (Express ?)

Comment: yes we are using express js server. Could you please provide me an example for sending it through wesocket or XHTML , I am completely new to NodeJS. Thanks.

Comment: For websockets you might need a small server that will IN/OUT data for you. so might need to do some reading about it.
XHTML is simple its just JavaScript function with in HTML that ask for information from another place 
There is documentation for it and some examples:
[XHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: @KrzysztofBuczynski its ejs why burden the poster with implementing exactly what ejs does again in sockets or rest? Examples are [here](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: @Dennington-bear well this is true I usually try to split my back end function with front end and call them through ajax when needed. I did not work much with express yet so just providing generic answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofBuczynski depends on the type of application but yes I agree usually when interacting with a db its better to have an api to connect with some type of auth. But i think this itself extends the scope of the question beyond what op asked

Comment: @Dennington-bear True. I come with an idea that its better to extend and do it right than create something that works but its not up to scratch.